# Construct a datatable from the REST response received from quering table entities in azure

Tags: xml, rest, azure, azure-table-storage

I query the Azure tables using REST API and the response is transformed to xmldocument. Is there an easy way to convert this xmldocument to datatable without manually parsing the xml in code? I would know the schema for the table/entity only at runtime.

Alternatively, what would be the best way to display the azure table data in a grid when you know about the table only at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of structure is in the xmldocument but have you tried

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
data.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(yourXmlDocument));
```